# synchronization Between two Servers Postgres Database

Tags: database, linux, postgresql

I have two postgres database in different linux server, the thing is that I want to synchronize all the data which are inserted , updated, deleted  in SERVER A to SERVER B. 
Is there any way to do this....? 
Any one help me ...?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since 9.0 PostgreSQL supplies it own [replication](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication). If you use 8.x you can try [other](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Replication) solutions.  Personally I used slony and was quite pleased with it.

Answer (score 3):

There are [many options](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling)...